The use of an article when describing a picture
I know that we don't use the definite article when we mention someone or something for the first time.
For example, when we are describing a picture we say,

There are apples on the table.

or

In this picture I can see a girl lying on a sofa.

or

These are cats.

We don't use the definite article in these cases, even if our listener look at this picture with us and know about what "apples", "cats" or "girl" we are talking about.
But recently I have come across a text in my book, which does use the definite article in this case. The text describes people in the picture. From the very beginning it says,

In this photo the people are doing a tour of a famous place.

Could you tell me please why we should use the definite article in this case?

No, you don't have to. But you can.

This question is similar to: Once you become a father, playing [ a / the ] super dad comes naturally. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Your rule is too strict.  When there is an obvious subject in the photo, we can use "the" when speaking of it for the first time. In this picture, the cat seems to be playing a piano.   or In this still life, the apples seem very shiny.
But if the subject is not obvious and the person you're speaking to is seeing the picture for the first time, or the picture is complicated with many possible subjects, for example a painting by Bruegel, to say something like "the kid with the hoop is wearing a blue hat" or "I wonder who the girl is hiding from" might elicit the reply "What kid with a hoop?" or "What girl? Where's the girl hiding?"
The purpose of the switch from indefinite article to definite article in the course of a conversation about a subject is to orient the listener gradually to the subject, your focus.  But if you use the in situations where the listener has not yet been oriented to the subject, the listener feels momentarily "lost" in the conversation.
The indefinite article and some descriptors move a subject into the "foreground", so to speak, and the definite article is used with something already  sufficiently foregrounded.

Excellent summary! If I remember, I'll try to make a point of duplicate closevoting in favour of this page when the next question about definite / indefinite article use comes along. Which probably won't be long, based on past experience!

@TimR Thank you TimR for your prompt reply! I just wanted to clarify your point. You said, "When there is an obvious subject in the photo, we can use "the" when speaking of it for the first time". I wonder whether I can still speak about "the people" in this case without the definite article, like "In this photo people are doing a tour of a famous place".

It would depend on whether there is a group of people isolated or otherwise prominent in the photo who would immediately appear to most people as the ones you're talking about.    We say "taking a tour", by the way,  in that context, not "doing a tour".   A person who has joined the military and is sent somewhere in the world is "doing a tour in {some country}".   But no article is required.  You could say "In this photo people are taking a tour of an ancient temple site".  If you want to make the people your focus, use the article. Then you can talk about them.  "They look tired and thirsty".

Or you could say "... people are taking a tour of a temple site. The people look tired and thirsty" -- in the sentence in which you make them your focus.

I don’t find ‘doing a tour’ unnatural-sounding here. ‘Taking a tour’ would imply (weakly) that it’s some kind of pre-organised tour, probably with a guide of some description, whereas ‘doing a tour’ leans more towards some people just walking around on their own; but both sound perfectly natural to me. I don’t find the definite ‘the people’ natural, though, especially paired with ‘a famous place’. The people being assumed familiar and the place unfamiliar jars to me; I would correct it to ‘some people are doing/taking a tour of a famous place’ or ‘the people in this photo are…’.

"doing a tour" is no less weak in its (putative) expression that the people are not led by a docent.   Is "doing a tour" a collocation that has that meaning in BrE? As for "a famous place", that's surely just a placeholder.

Thank you for your comment @Janus Bahs Jacquet! Your suggestion to say ‘the people in this photo are…’. instead of 'In this photo (the) people are...' seems quite interesting to me. The more so because I thought about it myself. If I understand correctly, the difference between them is that in ‘the people in this photo are…' we must use the definite article, because 'in this photo' goes as a prepositional phrase which specifies 'people'. Am I right?

Tim: I wasn’t aware it was dialectally limited, but I would say it is, yes. To me, it’s just an extension of constructions like ‘do a tour of the Mediterranean’ or ‘do a tour of the garden’, which are definitely both used in AmE. The guided vs non-guided distinction is not strong, but I at least would be more like to use take if it were a guided tour. // @Ola Yes, precisely.

@JanusBahsJacquet  "doing a tour" in AmE is used in connection with  itineraries.    "The prospective student is doing a tour of the campus at 1pm and then meeting with the soccer coach at  2:15."  It is different for that emphasis from "people taking a tour [of a famous place]".  "do a tour" and "take a tour" are not quite synonymous.

@Ola  "The people in this photo" would imply all of them and so  we would could say without article "People in this photo are staging a flash mob" since some of the people in the photo would be the audience of the performance not participants in the flash mob.  Not that we couldn't say "The people  ... are staging a flash mob".  That would present the flash mob as the subject of the utterance  as far as the speaker is concerned.  Language is presentation, and presentation is subjective and often arbitrary.  The language is grammatical even if the presentation is not objective.
